# Null Variable in Javascript Code

Tags: javascript

It keeps saying my variable is null even though it is assigned to a button in HTML. It doesn't allow the button press to work. The variable is "clickMe"

```
var yourName;   //global variable accessible to all functions

function showAnotherMessage() {
    alert("Hi " + yourName + ".\nThis is an alert message is no longer defined\nin the HTML but in a JavaScript file");
}

function init() {
    yourName = prompt("Hi. Enter your name.\nWhen the browser window is first loaded\nthe function containing this prompt window is called.", "Your name");
    var clickMe = document.getElementById("buttonclick");
  clickMe.onclick = showAnotherMessage;
    }

window.onload = init();
```

Comment: `var clickMe = document.getElementById("buttonclick");` ... do you have a html element with `id="buttonclick"` - exactly "buttonclick", not `"buttonClick"` or `"buttonclick "`

Comment: yes, the id is assigned to a button. <p><button type="button" id="buttonclick">Click Me!</button></p>

Comment: `window.onload = init();` should be `window.onload = init;`

Comment: wow, thankyou so much lol

Answer (score 2):

Avoid `window.onload` because it's fired too late in the page lifecycle - it's only fired after *everything* is loaded, including all images - which can be up to several seconds after the page has loaded.

Instead, use the DOM events API, and use the `DOMContentLoaded` event:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {

    // page startup code goes here
} );
```

Another reason to avoid `window.onload = ...` is that it will *overwrite* any previous event-handler for the `onload` event, whereas `addEventListener` does not remove any previous event handler.